# Is it possible to use lightning:navigation inside an aura:application?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, pagereference, navigation, lightningnavigation

What I need is a simple link to the org's home page. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) doesn't cover the case of `aura:application` but only cover the case of `aura:component`.

If I copy-paste the example inside an `aura:application` it throw an error:

> *navService.generateUrl is not a function*.

Is it possible to use `lightning:navigation` or any other solution to use links inside `aura:application`? I prefer to avoid hardcoding urls.

Comment: if you look at the top right side experience section of documentation mentioned it supports only "Lightning Experience, Salesforce Mobile App" so in your case "Standalone Lightning App" it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use [`lightning:navigation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) in an application.

If the Experience section of a Component's documentation does not list a particular experience, then that's not supported. In this case of `lightning:navigation`, the only supported experiences are:

- Lightning Experience
- Salesforce Mobile App

Your option here could be to use [`force:navigateToURL`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation) instead.

Comment: Can I use `force:navigateToURL` without hardcoding the URL? I simply need to redirect the user to the home page.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to hard code the URL, as long as you know the URL, you can have that as an attribute in your component, and utilize it in your JS.

Comment: It's still hardcoding. I means that the application will not work in sandboxes but only in the production org since I have to save the url in an attribute.

Comment: This topic is separate from the original ask of the question, but as a pointer there are ways to handle that how it can work in sandbox vs. production and that you don't need to necessarily hard code the URL in the attribute, you can always fetch it by making a server trip.